# Determining string values when implementing an insert() algorithm

Tags: string, algorithm, sorting, insert, comparison

I am currently going through some revision on my data structures and algorithm module, and have hit a sticky point, that I was wondering if anybody on here could clear up.

I'm working through the various insert() algorithms on the data structures, and have been faced with the issue of adding nodes to a binary search tree using the insert algorithm. This would normally not be a problem when inserting ints, however when inserting String objects into the tree, how would I go about comparing the String value within the node I am adding, to the String value within the node on the Binary Search tree, (in order to determine its position within the tree).

In other words, what gives one String a higher value than another String?

This may be a very simple answer, so apologies if so, but thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Some languages take care of this for you. For example, in Python, `someString1 > someString2` returns a consistent and sensible result based on alphabetic ordering.

Answer (score 1):

Strings are usually compared lexicographically.